# Use of ArgumentNullException when accessing arguments' properties

Tags: c#, exception, conventions

Suppose I have a class `Foo` with a complex property `Bar`. Then, suppose I have a method like the following in some other class:

```
public void DoSomething(Foo foo)
{
    if (foo == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
    if (foo.Bar == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
}
```

Is the use of an `ArgumentNullException` appropriate here even though, strictly speaking, `foo.Bar` is not an argument in this case? I [have read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792296/1043198) and can appreciate that it is not appropriate to throw a `NullReferenceException` manually. Is this telling me that I need to abstract?

```
public void DoSomething(Foo foo)
{
    if (foo == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("foo");
    DoSomethingElse(foo.Bar);
}

private void DoSomethingElse(Bar bar)
{
    if (bar == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bar");
}
```

Is my first code snippet the "correct" usage of `ArgumentNullException`? What is the conventional way of handling this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: You can throw `new ArgumentException("foo")` when it is not valid instance of `Foo` (e.g. one of it's properties is `null`)

Comment: Be aware when you are throwing an `ArgumentException` that the single string constructor expects a message [`new ArgumentException(string message)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxc6334.aspx).  If you are going to specify the parameter name use [`new ArgumentException(string message, string paramName)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxykka64.aspx).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ideally, the `Foo` class would ensure that its `Bar` property is never null. If that's not possible, I would throw an `ArgumentException` in this case since the argument is not null, but it is invalid.

Comment: Supposing that it's valid for `Foo.Bar` to be null, but `DoSomething` in particular needs `foo.Bar` to have a value, would you suggest that `DoSomething` should always handle this with a default execution path (returning a default value, if applicable) that does not throw an exception at all?

Comment: @AntP - That depends on what `DoSomething` does. If it's valid to return a default value then that might be preferable, but I would throw an exception rather than return some 'special' return value like null or -1.