# ArgumentNullException for nested members

Tags: c#, .net, validation, exception, argumentnullexception

Let's say I have a method:

```
public void SayHello(User user)
{
    if (user == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

    Console.Write(string.Format("Hello from {0}", user.Name));
}
```

It's clear that I should use ArgumentNullException as it shown above to validate that user is not null. Now how can I validate that user.Name is not empty? Would it be a good practice to do like that:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("user", "Username is empty");
```

Comment: If you place that code after the `user == null` check, then sure: that's perfectly fine. You already have the explicit guarantee at that point that `user` is not `null`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel that's clear. I'm just wondering is that a good practice to use ArgumentNullException that way. Should I consider any other exceptions for this?

Comment: I'd say you should not do that, and instead prefer the more robust approach, i.e., preventing a User with an empty username to begin with. You could make it so that the programmer should specify the username for all constructors of the `User` object, and throw the exception there. Then, you could expose the `UserName` property with a get only.

Comment: If you're checking whether or not the argument is null then `ArgumentNullException` is as to the point as it will get. This exception has been added exactly for this purpose. Note that you might want to look at the difference between `ArgumentException` and `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099218/use-of-argumentnullexception-when-accessing-arguments-properties

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you shouldn't throw [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this purpose as it is designed specifically to address `null` references.

> The exception that is thrown when a **null** reference (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid
>   argument.

Instead you should be using [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or your own subclass of it. let's say `InvalidUserException` or something similar.

[Even msdn talks about](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> ArgumentNullException behaves identically to ArgumentException. It is
>   provided so that application code can differentiate between exceptions
>   caused by null arguments and exceptions caused by arguments that are
>   not null. For errors caused by arguments that are not null

So it is clear that if argument is `null` use `ArgumentNullException` and `ArgumentException` otherwise.

That said, Ideally you shouldn't even allow someone to create an instance of `User` with invalid username. I'd really design my `User` class in such a way that it can never contain `Name` as `null`.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer

Answer (score 5):

You should throw `ArgumentException` if the argument is empty, `ArgumentNullException` should only be used for null arguments:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name))
    throw new ArgumentException("Username is empty", "user");
```