# Throwing an ArgumentNullException when a composed object is null

Tags: c#, .net-core, null

Is it recommended to throw an `ArgumentNullException` when the concerned argument is not `null` but one of its members is? For instance, if I have the following method:

```
public T Method(Blog blog)
{
    if (blog.Posts is null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(blog.Posts));
    }
}
```

For this method to complete its job, it requires that `blog.Posts` must not be `null`. Was the `ArgumentNullException` intended to be used this way? Or would it be misleading? If so, is there another specific exception type that better suits this use case or should I just rely on the default `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: I would throw `ArgumentException` for that, but I'd rather have `Blog` defined so that it can't have a null `Posts` member so that such an exception would be caught in the `Blog` constructor rather than the `Method()` call.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I agree. But there are cases when this isn't possible, for instance when the object comes from an external source or is deserialized; when an app uses Entity Framework, it usually does not load nested objects, even if there are multiple `Post` objects associated with a `Blog` in the database.  You have to chain a call to `Include()`  to ensure they are all loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of ArgumentNullException when accessing arguments' properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099218/use-of-argumentnullexception-when-accessing-arguments-properties)

Answer (score 2):

I think it makes more sense to create your own custom exception implementing the three common constructors. You can extend ArgumentNullException.

Comment: Generally, that doesn't seem very useful. For exceptions that should only ever be seen during development, creating separate exception types just makes code more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-5.0):

> An ArgumentNullException exception is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one of the passed arguments is null but should never be null.

So I think `ArgumentNullException` is the right one, because the property is part of the passed argument. Make sure, how you already did, to provide informations, what caused the Exception.

Comment: In addition, you can pass the name of the value that you expect to be instanciated as an agument to the exception constructor `throw new ArgumentException(nameof(blog.Posts))`

Comment: I would NOT use `nameof(blog.Posts)` because that would resolve to just `Posts` which could be quite confusing since the claimed parameter name wouldn't match the name of any actual parameter for that method.