# Does HandleError work anymore in Asp.net MVC 4 with razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, handleerror

I have the `[HandleError]` attribute set on my controller.

This is my action method:

```
    public ActionResult ShowError()
    {

        throw new NullReferenceException();
        return View();
    }
```

This action method has a corresponding view.

I have set custom errors in the config

```
<customErrors mode="On">     
</customErrors>
```

I have the `Error.cshtml` file in the shared folder under Views folder.

Now navigating to the `ShowError` controller method brings up this window in my IDE
[image]

On hitting F5 I get this in my browser window instead of the Error page from the shared folder.
[image]

What else is needed to be done to show the error page? How do I get the `HandleError` to work?

Thanks

Comment: check your `web.config` and set `debug="false"`.

Comment: You should not throw a `NullReferenceException` manually, it should be handled by Framework itself. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4792296/1551730)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. that takes care of the first one, but the handleError still needs to work

Comment: @Karthik: Throwing any exception results in the same 2nd image. Not the error page I have made for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So the problem was the browser I was using, which is IE 9. IE 9 seems to have problems showing an error page that is less than one KB. I put `@(new String(' ', 1000))` at the end of my error page and got it working.

Answer (score 1):

the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) states that

> To enable custom error handling for use by a HandleErrorAttribute
>   filter, add a customErrors element to the system.web section of the
>   application's Web.config file, as shown in the following example:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I am doing everything as per documentation. I saw a youtube video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-7Qa7JIvT0 where the demonstrator has got it working without using defaultRedirect. The only difference is he is using aspx and I am using Razor

Answer (score 0):

Your can put the name of the view in defaultRedirect="Error" as described by frictionlesspully or it can be specified in the HandleError attribute on an action, controller, or globally.

```
[HandleError(View="Error")]
```

The view can be named something other than "Error" if you specify it explicitly, e.g., "ServerError"

```
[HandleError(View="ServerError")]
```

You can also create a sub-folder w/in /Shared to group multiple error views if you want flexibility

/Shared/Errors/Server.cshtml

and then use the path in the attribute

```
[HandleError(View="Errors/Server")]
```

The folder where the controller and the /Shared folder are searched for the error view.